# Pie Chart Color

Tags: matlab, colors, matlab-figure, pie-chart

How can I create two different pie chart with different colors?
That it to say, I have to plot 2 different data:

1. One of them has Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday... (all days)
2. And the other one has Monday, Wednesday and Sunday.

I want that Monday in chart 1 and Monday in chart 2 to have the same color. The same thing for Wednesday, etc.
Tuesday and the other days which do not appear in the second plot in other color. Is it possible?

Using:

```
figure
X = rand(5, 1);
X = X/sum(X);
p = pie(X, {'M', 'T', 'W', 'TH', 'F'});
figure
X2 = rand(5, 1);
X2(2) = 0; % remove Tuesday from the plot
X2 = X2/sum(X2);
p = pie(X2, {'M', 'T', 'W', 'TH', 'F'});
```

gives:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A small hack is to set the values of the days that you want to show to *a very small positive value* and use an *empty char array* or a *char array with space characters* for their labels.

The smallest value in MATLAB can be returned using [`realmin('double')`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/realmin.html) or you can use [`eps`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html) or manually define a very small positive value.

```
figure
X = rand(7,1);
X = X/sum(X);
subplot(1,2,1);
p = pie(X,{'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'});

subplot(1,2,2);
X2 = rand(7,1);
X2([2,4,5,6]) = realmin('double');  %<----- Notice this (setting very small values)
X2 = X2/sum(X2);                                
p = pie(X2,{'Mon', '', 'Wed', '', '', '', 'Sun'});
%Notice this -------^----------^---^---^   No label for Tue, Thur, Fri, Sat
```

which gives:

[image: out]

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `CData` property of the underlying [`patch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch-properties.html) objects.
The command `p = pie(...)` returns an array of graphics objects, where the odd indices contain the patches for each pie segment and the even indices contain the text labels.

By default each patch has a single solid color given as a *relative* color index (according to the property `CDataMapping`). The only way I found to correctly sync different charts is to change these to *direct* indices to the colormap.

```
labels = {'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'};
data = 1:7;

% Draw first pie chart
figure
p1 = pie(data, labels);
% Set its colors to use direct colormap indices
set(p1(1:2:end), 'CDataMapping', 'direct')
% Spread colors evenly (default colormap has 64 colors)
for ii = 1:numel(p1)/2
    p1(ii*2-1).CData = ceil((ii / (numel(p1)/2)) * 64);
end

% Select indices of segments from first chart for the second chart
p1_indices = [1 3 7];

% Draw second pie chart
figure
p2 = pie(data(p1_indices), labels(p1_indices));
% Set its colors to use direct colormap indices
set(p2(1:2:end), 'CDataMapping', 'direct')
% Use the selected colors from the previous chart
for ii = 1:numel(p2)/2
    p2(ii*2-1).CData = p1(p1_indices(ii)*2-1).CData;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a pie chart with data that contains zeroes, the associated slice for that data is not rendered and is therefore not assigned a color index for the current colormap. The color indices for the `N` non-zero slices will span from `1:N`, such that they are [scaled](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch-properties.html#property_CDataMapping) to the [colormap limits](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#prop_CLim) (i.e. 1 corresponding to the first color in the colormap, `N` corresponding to the last color in the colormap).

To ensure consistency in slice coloring, you can change the [`'CData'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch-properties.html#property_d0e725922) of the slice [patches](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) to reproduce the color index values that would have been used if the zero slices were still present. Here's the code in a little helper function, where `data` is the input data to `pie` and `handles` is the array of graphics handles returned by `pie`:

```
function recolor_pie(data, handles)
  if all(data > 0)
    return  % No changes needed
  end
  C = get(handles(1:2:end), 'CData');   % Get color data of patches
  N = cellfun(@numel, C);               % Number of points per patch
  C = mat2cell(repelem(find(data > 0), N), N);  % Replicate indices for new color data
  set(handles(1:2:end), {'CData'}, C);  % Update patch color data
end
```

Here's an example showing its use:

```
% Plot first pie chart:
figure('Color', 'w');
subplot(1, 2, 1);
X = rand(5, 1);
X = X./sum(X);
p = pie(X, {'M', 'T', 'W', 'TH', 'F'});

% Plot second pie chart:
subplot(1, 2, 2);
X2 = rand(5, 1);
X2(2) = 0; % remove Tuesday from the plot
X2 = X2./sum(X2);
p = pie(X2, {'M', 'T', 'W', 'TH', 'F'});
recolor_pie(X2, p);
```

[image]

And now the colors are consistent between the pie charts.